# Kotlin executes only one of two suspend functions

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

In my suspend function `getContent` I am calling two other suspend functions:

```
override suspend fun getContent(token: String) {
...
                    getUserPosts(token)
                    getRecentPosts(token)
    ...

}
```

But only the first one gets executed.
If I put `getRecentPosts` first then only that one gets executed.

How to solve this?

I call the `getContent` method from ViewModel with `viewModelScope`.

*EDIT*
Here is my getUserPosts() method, the getRecentPosts() method look pretty much the same, the "Finished 1" and "Finsihed 2" Log is getting logged but not "Finished 3:

```
override suspend fun getUserPosts(token: String) {
    try {
        myInterceptor.setAccessToken(token)
        graphqlAPI.query(GetUserPostsQuery()).fetchPolicy(FetchPolicy.NetworkFirst).watch()
            .collect { response ->
                val newList = arrayListOf<Post>()
                response.data?.getUserPosts?.let {
                    for (post in it) {
                        newList.add(
                            Post(
                                id = post.postFragment.id,
                                ...
                            )
                        )

                    }
                    userState.editUserState(userState.userStateFlow.value?.copy(posts = newList))
                    Log.i("#+#", "Finished 1")
                }
                Log.i("#+#", "Finished 2")
            }
        Log.i("#+#", "Finished 3")
    } catch (e: ApolloException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the functions `getUserPosts(token)` and `getRecentPosts(token)` are infinite and they don't finish execution. Please check that.

Comment: Please show the content of these two functions.

Comment: Is any of those functions collecting something? Is any of those functions throwing an exception?

Comment: can the getRecent function return null or/and can it throw an exception?

Comment: @Sergio  I updated my question with the function in it

Comment: @Tenfour04 I updated my question with the function in it

Comment: @cutiko I updated my question with the function in it

Comment: @writer_chris I updated my question with the function in it

Comment: response.data is not null?

Comment: @writer_chris It's just logging my response array.
I think its because I'm collecting a flow in those suspend functions? So it ofc never finishes. But how to collect two flows at the same time?

Comment: aCoroutine{ stateflowA.combine(stateflowB){ sfA,sfB-> when....}.collect{_state.emit(it)} if it is stateflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collect` never stops, so the first function will never end.

What you have to do is launch another coroutine inside.

```
override suspend fun getContent(token: String) {
      CoroutineContex.launch { getUserPosts(token) }                    
      CoroutineContex.launch { getRecentPosts(token) }

}
```

However that is considered dirty because you can't test it. That `launch` there won't have the same scope than the coroutine scope from testing.
Also, it won't stop, so it is better to provide the coroutine scope.

```
override suspend fun getContent(token: String, coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
      coroutineScope.launch { getUserPosts(token) }                    
      coroutineScope.launch { getRecentPosts(token) }

}
```

This way in your view model or fragment you can call it "safely" by knowing the scope will cancel the collection when the owner life cycle ends.

```
getContent(token, viewModelScope)
```

```
getContent(token, viewLifeCycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

This is not an uncommon doubt, and there is a fairly brief mention on the documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecycle-aware

Comment: Okay thank you very much! That solves my problem. Didn't knew you could easily pass the coroutineScope without worrying.

Comment: @HavanaSun you should worry, this seems like an indication of bad design, if those are HTTP requests there is no point in collecting.

Comment: Thats the nature of GraphQL Watchers. They collect every change made to the cached items and rerun the code inside collect()

Comment: @HavanaSun Ho! I see now `graphqlAPI` my apologies; thanks for teaching me.